# Pycharm project panel next search result

Tags: search, pycharm, project

In Pycharm when focus is on the project panel, where the tree view of files and folders of the project are, you can type.

This will select the first occurrence of a file or folder that contains the typed string. Also there is a small box that apears at the top left that says: Search for [string].

What I can't figure out is how to navigate past the first result. 
I've tried Ctrl+G, Ctrl+F, Arrows, ENTER, PAGE_DOWN, TAB with no success, they either do nothing or navigate the tree itself, rather then the search results.

Is there a way to navigate the search results?

I can't find any documentation for this existing search feature, let alone for the navigation keys.

If this isn't possible; what's the best way to list all files and folders containing a string, inside of a project, inside or outside of Pycharm.

Pycharm version:
PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.3
Build #PC-163.15188.4, built on March 10, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate through the search results in that pane.

There are also menu options under the **Navigate** menu in PyCharm that give you other search options. You can read about those in [Navigating to Class, File or Symbol by Name](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html).

Comment: Works, however it seems that it only shows currently visible items. So my test-case was flawed .

Also just ARROWS work.